# Signature level protection not working

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, apk, signature

I am signing my service.apk with a certificate C1 and my activity.apk with certificate C2 and I have put in the manifest file of the service

```
e<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="yo.myservice"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:protectionLevel="signature"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
 android:protectionLevel="signature"     
 android:label="@string/app_name">
    <service android:name=".yoService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="yo.myservice.yoService" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </service>
</application>
```

But i still see that the activity is able to bind to the service and call its functions.

My understanding acc to what is mentioned [Android Security](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel) was that activity wont be able to access service unless its signed by the same certificate. I am on Android platform 2.2.

Could some one let me know where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:protectionLevel` is a valid attribute for [`<permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html). You have it on [`<manifest>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) and on [`<application>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html), and it is not valid for either of those.

Comment: I had changed the manifest to now have     <permission android:name="yo.myservice.yoService"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />  but its still not working.

Comment: @Titus: Make sure you followed all the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms